# get widget name by on touching the elements in Activity android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

By using below code how to get widget name (`Edittext`, `Button`, `Textview` etc...) by on touching or onclicking the elements in an activity. can anyone please help me...

```
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    switch(ev.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
          break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
          break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
          break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the view by implementing `OnClickListener`, where you will get the clicked view in a click callback.

```
Button button;
String name;

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        name = v.getClass().getSimpleName();
        // name = "Button"
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but this is for particular button rite?. i need to get widget name by clicking any places in an activity.

Comment: It's not clear to me then what exactly you need. Do you want to get, for example, the name of your Activity/Fragment/etc class?

Comment: for example there is a lot of elements in my activity. texview, linnearlayout, edittext etc. when i touch on the screen, i want to know what element i touched?